# How to delete a row in el-table by using vue js

Tags: vue.js

Here is my el-table code-

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <el-table :data="membersList">
      <el-table-column label="Name" prop="member_name" align="center">
      </el-table-column>
      <el-table-column label="Email" prop="member_email">
      </el-table-column>
      <el-table-column label="Role" prop="member_role"> </el-table-column>
      <el-table-column
        align="center"
        label="Designation"
        prop="member_designation"
        ></el-table-column>
      <el-table-column
        align="center"
        label="Country"
        prop="member_country"
        ></el-table-column>
      <el-table-column label="Operations">
        <template slot-scope="scope">
          <base-button
            type="info"
            @click="editMember(scope.$index, scope.row)"
            class="btn-sm mr-2"
            >Edit</base-button
            >
          <base-button
            type="danger"
            @click="deleteMember(scope.$index, scope.row)"
            class="btn-sm"
            >Delete</base-button
            >
        </template>
      </el-table-column>
    </el-table>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm expecting to delete the rows from the table by clicking the delete button. The data rendering from the backend server, now I added the delete button but don't know how to create a function to delete the row when clicking on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the index of the row, so just use `vue.delete` **(this.$delete)** like this-

```
deleteMember(index, row) {
  this.$delete(this.membersList, index);
},
```

Read more about `vue.delete` in the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-delete).